# AWS API Gateway - Add wrapper functions for encrypting entire payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am working on doing an end-to-end encryption of data transfer between server and client..

Without touching the application code, can I add this as a layer in the API Gateway using some additional side car like Lambda ?

I am on AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do a sidecar Lambda in API Gateway. What you could do is send all your API Gateway traffic to Lambda, which could then issue requests to the backend application, obtain the results, and then encrypt the results before returning the response to API Gateway.

Comment: Is that a good pattern ? Does it create bottlenecks in my architecture ? Is it better if I do this decrypt / encrypt in each micro-service behind the api gateway ?

Comment: "Is that a good pattern?" That's a matter of opinion. "Does is create bottlenecks in my architecture?"  Probably not, unless you run into concurrency limits with Lambda. "Is it better if I do this decrypt / encrypt in each micro-service behind the api gateway?" That is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Can I ask you what is your opinion on the questions in above comment ?

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/data-protection-encryption.html